# Преобразование текста

Tags: c#

Подскажите как можно сделать так:

Например имеем строку "красивая платье" ее нужно изменить на "красивое платье"?

Возможно есть какие-то библиотеки для C# чтобы можно было текст исправлять с корявого на почти нормальный.

Comment: Можно использовать например [спеллчекер ворда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31969800/12888024), [можно самому написать](https://habr.com/ru/post/105450/). Наверняка и операционная система такой сервис имеет, но я не изучал.

Comment: @AK, такие библиотеки есть, по крайней мере платные: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2635/controls-and-libraries/spell-checker